# Web Automation in C#

Tags: vb.net, c#-4.0, webautomation

```
WebPageDoc.getElementById("secNavTab:secTabsId").getElementsByTagName("div")(0).getElementsByTagName("table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")(2).Click()
```

In VB.Net this code is working fine but when i am trying to write this code into C#, i am getting an Error "mshtml.IHTMLElement does not contain a definition for getElementByTagName and no extension method getElementsByTagName accepting a first argument type mshtml.IHTMLElement could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Please Help me in this :(

Comment: The code snippet you show has "getElementsByTagName" with an "s" but the error message you quote has "getElementByTagName" *without* and "s" - could that be the problem or is it a typo in the question?

Comment: No its not the typo error, actually 's' was left by mistake.